# multiple tables in html/css

Tags: html, css

Basically I'm trying to have to have 2 tables on the page but in different positions, I've tried using `<table class="">` but nothing is happening. I know the code is a a bit messy/amateur but I'm a very beginner as of right now.

HTML

```
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <td> <a href="hawaii.html"> Park Narodwy Hawaii </a> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <a href="yellowstone.html"> Park Narodwy Yellowstone </a> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <a href="lassen.html"> Park Narodwy Lassen Volcanic </a> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table2">
<tr> 
<td> Położenie </td> <td> Hawaje (Stany Zjednoczone) </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Data utworzenia </td> <td> 1916 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Powierzchnia </td> <td> 1348 km² </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Współrzędne </td> 
</tr>
```

CSS

```
.table1 {
  border: 10px solid #000;
  margin-top: 39px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}


.table2 {
border: 10px solid #000;
margin-top: 60px;
margin-right: 50px;
}
```

[somethinglikethis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avny1.png)
[attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CH6x.png)

Comment: Put the code as a code snippet so we can edit (Y).

Comment: @Julia..  Where are you trying to move them to?  One left, one right? One top right, one bottom left?

Comment: @user2796515 one needs to be in the top left but one has to be underneath some text

Comment: @julia.  The code would be `Your table 1 HTML` and then `some text` and then `Your table 2 HTML` and remove the CSS for margins.  I would add this answer but I'm sure this is not what you mean, but it seems like it from your response.  See here: https://jsfiddle.net/14ehhjnc/1/

Comment: @user2796515 the problem is that the first table is somewhat of a menu (in the top left) and the text is centered. For example looking at this site the blog section would be table 1 and my code would be table2 I hope that's pretty understandable.

Comment: @Julia. Sorry, not sure I understand, maybe make an image of you want and I can try to help.

Comment: @user2796515 I attached an image to the question, I would appreciate if you could take a look.

Comment: @Julia, I have added an answer, trying to duplicate your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put your tables inside of divs and added `float: left;` to align them to the left. `Table2` still has its own class inside the `#someText` div so it can be moved lower if need be.

This is the updated css, please see this fiddle for update with HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/14ehhjnc/3/

```
#tbl1 
{
  border: 10px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  float:left;
}
#someText
{
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.table2 {
border: 10px solid #000;
margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to move the 2nd table further right? (I attached a picture of how it looks now)

Comment: @Julia, do you mean the text and the table, or just table 2?  To move the text and table further right, you would increase margin-left to #someText like this: https://jsfiddle.net/14ehhjnc/7/  If you want to just move table2 add margin-left to the table2 class like this: https://jsfiddle.net/14ehhjnc/6/

Comment: @Julia glad to help, please accept my answer if it was useful - good luck with your project!